# $wpdb->get_results issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a $wpdb->get_results query that looks like this:

```
"SELECT *
 FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_author = $current_user_id
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   AND post_type = 'event'
 ORDER BY post_date DESC"
```

It translates to:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_author = 5
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  AND post_type = 'event'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

If I run that exact query in the database via phpmyadmin, it returns results perfectly fine. In the wordpress implementation however it doesn't return anything. 
I've narrowed it down to the `AND post_type = 'event'` part that seems to be breaking it. When I leave that away from the query, it returns results just fine

Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a Registered Custom Post type called 'event'? And do you have any entries in your database with post_type event?

Comment: Are you sure $current_user_id = 5?  And are you sure you're running both queries against the same database?

Comment: phpMyAdmin might modify queries by adding `LIMIT 0, 30` to them, but it shouldn't create such a difference.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, wordpress has 5 major post types: (post, page, attachment, revision, and nav_menu_item )

In order to look up a post_type of 'event' you need to have registered this custom post type using the `register_post_type`function.

Here is a sample of how you might create a custom post type called 'event'

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'event',
        array(
            'labels' => array('name' => __( 'events' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'event' )),
            'public' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Note: `register_post_type($post_type, $args)` takes 2 arguments by default.

`$post_type` - is the name of your custom post type.

`$args` - is any number of arguments to modify the default behavior of the post type. This should usually be an array.

The `'labels'` argument describes the name of the post type in general and singular form. If you prefer to have general and singular versions of the post type then use the method shown. Otherwise the default is just the `$post_type name` name that you supplied.

`'public'` argument says if the post type is intended for public use.

You can also write a simplified version without many tags such as:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'event', array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'events' ) );
}
```

Also note that `create_post_type` is a custom name for a function that you could call `my_super_cool_new_custom_original_post_type_creating_function` haha or something descriptive for your needs.

In the simplified version I used `label` which takes a single argument and that is the general name of the post type. If you would like to add a description for your post types you would do it within the parentheses for the name and replace one underscore for an x such as:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
register_post_type( 'event',
    array(
        'labels' => array('name' => _x( 'events' , 'post type general name' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'event' , 'post type singular name' )),
        'public' => true,
    )
);
```

Word of caution: Do not use `register_post_type` before init.

Now, if you have done all of this and you can't access the post_type, ensure you have added the public argument to it. :)

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using     `post_type like %event%`

You can execute the same thing via WP_Query query_posts, this is not a complicated query where you need to use $wpdb but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try the below code :

```
$get_post = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_author = ".$current_user_id."
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  AND post_type = 'event'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
");
```

OR

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
 FROM $wpdb->posts
 WHERE post_author = $current_user_id
   AND post_status = 'publish'
   AND post_type = 'event'
 ORDER BY post_date DESC", OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was coming from the new lines. For some reason either the editor or the db was configured wrong, as it was never happened to me.

Once I changed the query to be on the same lines it started to work.